# Dynamically add list to a list in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have:

```
var myList: MutableList<MutableList<Int>>
```

and I want to dynamically create a list `(i, j)` which are `Int` and it is to the `myList`.

I tried

```
myList.add(mutableListOf(i,j))
```

But it doesn't work.
Firstly I get `error: variable 'myList' must be initialized`
And I am not sure that's the right way to make a list on the go and add it to a list of lists

Answer (score 3):

As the error mentions, you have to initialize the list before using it.

`var myList: MutableList<MutableList<Int>>` with this you just declare its type.

`var myList = mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>()` with this you have empty list. After that you can freely add another list inside it as an element.

Answer (score 0):

Use buildList, buildSet or buildMap. Check documentation of [buildList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html) function.

Answer (score -1):

initialize the list

```
var myList: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.